# Why are two double integrals necessary for this area? [Probability]

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

This is a probability question where I am asked to integrate a region that represents the probability of a scenario. X, Y, and U are random variables, where U = X-Y. I need to find the probability

$P(U \leq u) = P(X-Y \leq u)$, where the density function I'm integrating over is defined by f(x,y) = 1, for 0 $\leq x \leq 2 \quad 0 \leq y \leq 1 \quad 2 y \leq x$.

Why can't I capture this region with a single double integral going from $\int_{0}^{1}$$\int_{2y}^{u+y}$dxdy ?

Comment: Which constraint of two $x-y\le u$ and $u=x-y$ is valid?

Answer (score 0):

As the question is written, you don't need an integral at all.  You want $x-y \le u$, which means $x-y \le x-y$, which is always true, so you can ignore $u$.  You are left with the other three constraints which give a $1-2-\sqrt 5$ right triangle with area $1$.

Comment: When discussing probability: $X-Y\leq u$ is not the same as $x-y\leq u$.  $U$ is a random variable, $u$ is a value, $x,y$ are bound variables of the integral.

Comment: @GrahamKemp:  the question has been edited.  There was no mention of probability, nor of capital $X$ and $Y$ when I answered.

Comment: Fair enough....

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: make sure the contraint intersects the support: $$\{(x,y):\underbrace{~x-y\leq u~}_{\text{constraint}}\wedge\underbrace{~ 2y\leq x\leq 2~\wedge~ 0\leq y\leq 1~}_\text{support}\}$$
That is: $$\{(x,y): \max\{1-u/2,0\}\leq y\leq 1~\wedge~2y\leq x\leq\min\{2, u+y\}\}$$

Further if $U=X-Y$ then $\min(U)=\min(X-Y) = 0$ and $\max(U)=\max(X-Y)=2$

So:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(U\leq u) &= \int_0^1\int_{\max\{2y,u+y\}}^{\min\{2, u+y\}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y\cdot\mathbf 1_{u\in[0;2)}+\mathbf 1_{u\in[2;\infty)}\end{align}$$